# connecting to Windows VM from the headless server

Tags: windows, headless

I've setup a Ubuntu headless server and installed a Windows VM on it. I can perfectly connect to it from a remote computer but.... I cannot connect to the Windows VM from the headless server.
Is there a way to connect to the Windows VM from the headless server?

Comment: The Windows VM has a GUI attached.  The Headless Server by default doesn't have the functionality to display the GUI.  Unless you've configured the Windows system to have SSH on it or some similar remote management utility, there's no *direct* way on a Windows VM to 'connect' to the Windows VM from the headless server for management (which because Windows requires a GUI first)

Comment: So if I find a way to install SSH on the Windows VM then it should be possible. My intention is, while I am working at my Ubuntu server I connect to the Windows VM. The screen I see is the Windows screen of the VM.

Comment: Then you shouldn't have gone with a *headless* server to run the Windows VM.  You would've needed a GUI to achieve what you're after.  You still won't get that even with SSH.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize the comments, you want to do the following:

1. Connect to the (headless aka "No GUI") Ubuntu server, and then
2. See the Windows VM in a GUI.

The core problem is: the server is headless with no GUI.

**Your goals and the server type you're using for the hypervisor** (called a "Type 2 Hypervisor" but without the GUI / "head" components) **cancel each other out, resulting in a mutually-exclusive-options type of situation**.

To connect to the server *and* see the GUI from the headless server is impossible.  You would need to set up a GUI inside the Ubuntu server, and then very likely use a software that hooks into the 'console' within the hypervisor software.

***This requires that you have a GUI on the server itself, if you do not intend to connect directly into the VM with Remote Desktop, VNC, or some other type of 'screensharing' solution.***  Even if you install SSH on the Windows server to remotely connect to it, you're then limited to a CLI connection.

Therefore, unless your virtualization software allows you to run a VNC connection for the VM, *and* the VM is directly connected to the 'network' that the Ubuntu Server sits on (aka a "bridged connection"), *and* you are willing to connect directly to the Windows VM, *and* you manage to set up that functionality (which is tricky on the Command Line, and requires you to ask how to do that over on Super User), **your goal and what you've done so far prohibit you from achieving your goal, no matter what you do to the VM or the host server.**

Without the GUI on the server, you've got no chance of achieving your ultimate goals here.  And without the GUI, you can't really manage the Windows VM to get everything set up as you need to in order to have the Windows VM connectable directly (which requires editing registry values, enabling/disabling features, and/or installing additional software on Windows to make remote connections over VNC work directly).